# osx mac id3 tag finding the actually version #

Tags: macos, id3

Numerous mp3s. All have id3 tags. I want to know what the tag version is on a specific mp3. I do not see this information in iTunes. So, I do not know if it is 1,2,2.x, etc. I also have MusicBrainz as an option, but still do not see id3 version displayed anywhere. 
Q) Do either of these applications display id3 tag version information? Are there simple command line programs which will display tag version on all the different versions? 2.x, 2.x+1, 2.x+2 etc...

Thx

Comment: This site is for programming questions. We are not here to find an MP3 management app for you.

Comment: Yeah, just saw this belongs on a sister site.